# Why does the EF 6 not recognize my Firebird database provider?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, firebird2.5

I try to connect to a new Firebird database in EF 6 via code first attempt. The system does not create the database before i try to insert something and does not find the db provider i give into app.config.

My project lives in a library Project where all the EF stuff is done and a console app that show my returning data.

I have following NuGet packages installed into the project.

- EntityFramework.6.1.3
- EntityFramework.Firebird.4.8.1
- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.4.8.1.1

My Configuration is as little follows the convention over configuration approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
            <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SoftwareContext" connectionString="database=localhost:Inventory;user=user;password=password;ServerType=0;" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The model consists of a simple POCO implementation with no annotations.

```
public class Software
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Version VersionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the SoftwareContext.

```
public class SoftwareContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Software> Programs { get; set; }

    public SoftwareContext()
    {  }
}
```

When i run it all seems to work fine until i create an Software object and add it to the collection. It throws me the following System.NotSupportedException:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
```

When i explicitely change my constructor of the SoftwareContext to:

```
public SoftwareContext() : base(new FbConnection(constring), true)
```

I get the following System.NotSupportedException thrown when i try the same operation:

```
Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

When i check for the existing DbProviderFactories in the constructor of my SoftwareContext class the list only shows other providers.

1. System.Data.Odbc
2. System.Data.OleDb
3. System.Data.OracleClient
4. System.Data.SqlClient
5. System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0

When i let me give the Database.DefaultConnectionFactory it always shows me System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory not the given default from app.config.

All the DLLs for EF and Firebird are set to local copies in the output. So they are all available at runtime. The database is a standard 2.5.5 installation no embedded version.

I found some topics about the not working migrations for EF and Firebird, but they are mostly getting other problems.

Why does the EF not recognize my database provider sitting in the configuration and therefore does not create a db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the configuration used by .NET is not the specified in the library's config file, but the one in the main project. I.e. if you app is a web site, you need to spceify your configuration in the `web.config`. If it's a console or desktop app, you need to add your configuration to the `app.config` of that project. And, if you want to run integration tests, you need to add the configuration to the test project.

In all other regards, it looks like your [configuration is correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx).

Comment: It workes now when i copied over the configuration from the library projects app.config to the executables app.config. Now i get a System.TypeInitializationException saying "The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception." The VS editor says the configuration file is proper formatted. I poke around a bit to look what happens :)

Comment: Have you installed the EF firebird provider to the executable project? It's possible it cannot read the config because it requires the firebird assembly. If you start your app in debug mode Visual Studio shpuld stop on the execption. If so, you can check if some inner execption has more concrete information

Comment: Yes, i reinstalled the provider and added it also to the executable project. Now i can use it like intended. Thank you.